# Clean database in production

Tags: django, postgresql

I successfully deployed my website on Linode on a Ubuntu server.
I am using Postgres for database.

I can perform all the actions correctly.

However, I would like to clean my database (deleting all the users, posts, files, etc. that I created for my "in production" testing).

I generally use:

```
python manage.py flush
```

when I want to clean my database of all of its elements (not tables) in development.

Can I use the same command in production using the bash on my Ubuntu server? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

The django documentation mentions why you might want to drop the database instead of flush.   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#flush

If you want to re-run migrations (re-create tables), you should drop the database.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS name;
```

Where name is the name you gave your database.

If you just want to clear the database, that's what flush is for.  It generates the SQL statements to clear all your tables so you don't have to :)